# What to do with IO handles when you want to chain constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, io

I have a simple class that accepts an `InputStream` of a known format in its constructor. All of the heavy lifting is done in this constructor before assigning values to the private members of the object:

```
public class TestClass {
   private Integer something;
   
   public TestClass(InputStream istream) {
      // Long and complex something-something
      // ...
      
      // Assign value after lots of processing
      something = 123;
   }
}
```

Now I've decided that I also want to provide a constructor that accepts a `File`. I can easily chain constructors like this:

```
public TestClass(File file) {
   this(new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

Uh oh! I forgot to close the stream!

```
public TestClass(File file) {
   InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(file);
   
   try {
      // Error: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
      this(istream);
   }
   finally {
      istream.close();
   }
}
```

Chaining constructors in this way isn't allowed. Java says that calling a constructor from another constructor must be the first statement.

I tried to stuffing everything into a method that handles initialization but the Java compiler still yells at me about my constructors having uninitialized variables:

```
public class TestClass {
   private Integer something;
   
   // Error: The field something may not have been initialized
   public TestClass (InputStream istream) {
      doInit();
   }
   
   // Error: The field something may not have been initialized
   public TestClass (File file) {
      InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(file);
      
      try {
         doInit(istream);
      }
      finally {
         istream.close();
      }
      
   }
   
   private void doInit(InputStream istream) {
      something = 123;
   }
}
```

Besides simply removing the constructor that accepts a `File` and only accepting a stream, is there a way to make this work as presented?

My actual code has multiple member variables being initialized so it's not as simple as passing the stream to a static method and returning a value since this would only initialize at most a single variable.

Comment: Can't you close it in the main constructor? Is there a case where you do not want to close it, or are you potentially reading many such objects from the stream?

Comment: Use a static factory method.

Comment: @Bohemian I could close all streams that have been passed into the constructor. But it feels like an odd behavior to have a constructor close a stream for me, even if I were to expect the stream to be read fully.

Comment: @Bohemian The convention, as I understand it, is to _never_ close a resource that your code did not open itself.

Comment: The static factory method seems like a good option. Open the `FileInputStream` in the static method (using try-with-resources) and then simply `return new TestClass(fis);`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a static method:

```java
public class TestClass {

  public static TestClass fromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      return new TestClass(input);
    }
  }

  public TestClass(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    // initialize instance...
  }
}
```